# Incorrect page shown

Tags: urls

I am creating a website for someone to replace their old site. I put the URL of the old site into into the site address in my general settings, and now I can’t get it to change back to the site I was building

The page I need help with: http://35.230.137.15/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the general settings URL if you have access to the database by executing the SQL statement:

```
UPDATE wp_options 
SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl')
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

'http://www.oldurl' -- Change this to the URL you set in general settings

'http://www.newurl' -- Change this to what you want the URL to be